# WSO2ESB doesn't startup with informix

Tags: java-8, java.util.scanner, informix, wso2, wso2-esb

I installed WSOESB 5.0.0 on a ubuntu server with the default database H2. It worked fine.But I don't want to use H2. I want to use informix. So I check the step to configured it with Informix database server. The informix database is not installed on the ubuntu server. Is installed on a unix server.  So I installed the JDBC driver 4.10 in carbon_home/repisitory/conf/lib. Changed the datasource.xml to refer to the server were I run the informix.sql script to create the database and tables.

When I start sh wso2server.sh. I am getting an database error.

This is the Error:

```
Error databaseUtil error database java.SQLException.
```

My Informix server is installed on a HP-UX platform running in 11.31 U ia64. The JDBC drivers that I am using for the ESB platform that is installed on a Ubuntu 14.04 is JDBC4.10.JC8DE. I attached a printscreen of the errors that I am getting after running the ESB application.

```
root@ubun# sh wso2server.sh

JAVA_Home environment variable is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/ CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /opt/wso2esb-5.0.0 
Using Java memory options: Xms256 -Xmx1024m 
[2017-02-21 05:05:46,876] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon ...
[2017-02-21 05:05:46,881] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Linux 3.13.0-109-genetric, amd64
[2017-02-21 05:05:46,882] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
[2017-02-21 05:05:46,882] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version : 1.8.0_121
[2017-02-21 05:05:46,882] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM : Java HotSpot (TM) 64-Bit Server vm 25.121-b13, Oracle Corporation
[2017-02-21 05:05:46,882] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home : /opt/wso2esb-5.0.0
[2017-02-21 05:05:46,882] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir : /opt/wso2esb-5.0.0/tmp
[2017-02-21 05:05:46,883] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User : root, en_Us, America/Paramaribo
[2017-02-21 05:05:47,199] INFO - Kafka EventAdapterServiceDS succesfully deployed the Kafka output event adapter service.
[2017-02-21 05:05:47,324] INFO - ManagementModeConfigurationLoader CEP started in single node mode
[2017-02-21 05:05:49,124] ERROR - DatabaseUtil Database Error - null java.sql.SQLException.
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:290)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.barrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.poolConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:158)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:448)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:124)
at org.wso2.carboj.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:263)
```

I hope someone can tell me what the problem is?

Comment: There are several key pieces of information missing that would help identify/resolve the issue. Can you give the exact version of Informix server and the platform where Informix is installed? What is the full version (including fix pack) of the JDBC driver? Can you post the first 10 lines of the java exception message?

Comment: Pradeep I already posted the information that you ask. I hope this is enough.

Comment: This is good information but still not enough. What I gather from the java exception is that the client application is not able to establish a database connection. I can't tell why (yet)!
You said Informix is running in an HP IA64 system. What is the port number where Informix is listening. Is Informix configured with the right protocol (soctcp)? 
When you configured the data source in WSO2 ESB, what is the JDBC connection URL you are using? Make sure it is the right format for Informix.

Comment: The connection URL for Informix should look like:
jdbc:informix-sqli://123.45.67.89:1533/testDB

Comment: In the datasource I had configured the Url and the drivername of imformix. The connectipn Url is is the same like yours except for the portnumber, ipadres and databasenaam. My portnumber is 9088.

Comment: Ok, glad you verified the connection URL. If you are trying to create the database, then don't specify the database name in the connection URL. You will get the connection error if you try to connect to a non-existent (yet to be created) database!
Also make sure the driver name is specified as `com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver`

Comment: Pradeep the database is already created in informix with tables etc. It was created succesfully. That was created before I specify the databasename. Also the driver name was changed to com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver before I started ESB. I checked everything. I don't know what could be wrong. I am still getting the same Error.

Comment: Hello, Edmyra. From the application machine, can you do a telnet to the informix host, on the specified 9088 port? That's a nice try to catch if your app box is reaching the engine box.

Comment: I did a telnet from the application server to the  db server and I could login. When I do a telnet from the application server to the  database with port number. I get connected to ....  escape character is '^]'. Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: The same Error occurs. ERROR databaseUtil error database java.SQLException.

Comment: @EdmyraPlein It is also possible that the user/pwd you are trying to connect with doesn't have the right permissions for that database. 
I recommend this:  
- Install Informix ClientSDK (free download from IBM) in your Ubuntu system.  
- Configure the sqlhosts file (<installation dir>/etc/sqlhosts) to be able to connect to the Informix server.  
- Run dbaccess (<installation dir>/bin/dbaccess) and try connecting to the same database.  
If this succeeds, then we can rule out all the connectivity issues.

Comment: @Pradeep I use Informix as user and informix has all privilleges.  But I will download the informix Client SDK from IBM and install it. I will give you the results when I am finished.